# Using angular-router to navigate views within a page

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-routing, angular7-router

I'm creating a web application with multiple pages, and within each page there are dynamic sections. I'd like each of these sections to use the angular router.

I've tried simply putting a named router-outlet inside the components, but it doesn't seem to work... Any thoughts?

Here's my general setup.

**App template**

```
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

**App module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { 
  path: 'page', 
  component: PageModule
 }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [PageModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Page template:**

```
<tabset>
  <tab>
    <router-outlet name="section1"></router-outlet>
  </tab>
  <tab>
    <router-outlet name="section2"></router-outlet>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**Page module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'section1-view1',
    component: View1Component,
    outlet: 'section1',
  },
  {
    path: 'section1-view2',
    component: View2Component,
    outlet: 'section1',
  }
  // More routes ...
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PageComponent,
    View1Component,
    View2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    TabsetModule
  ]
})
export class PageModule { constructor(){} }
```

Comment: Are you looking for the route to determine what tab to show or determine what is shown on each tab?

Comment: do you want to route in the routed pages?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you mean that each section should have a url link? like in angular docs pages? (like this link: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity)

Comment: @KautilyaKatiha, Yes! I want to route within the routed pages. :)

Comment: I'd want the content of each tab to be controlled by the route, and I want these tabs to be on pages which are also included via the router.

Comment: If I replace the root router-outlet with just the PageComponent then the code above works, but I want to route to the PageComponent as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make each component in a new module then define the internal routes in that module, so whenever you route to the module, you can route in the internal routes.

keep your current routes as they are, and declare new module(import these modules in `app.module`), and within that module make new components where you want to route in that module.

check this out: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8apbns) Just a sample example for your use.

Here there is one component in `app.module` and a module called `intmodule` and there are two components in `intmodule`.
From the `app.module` we can route between `hello.component` and `intmodule` and in `intmodule` we can route between comp1 and comp2.

comment for more help :)

Comment: I believe this is what I'm doing that isn't working. Can you provide an example?

Comment: check the stackblitz I added. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Try this one

create two separate components to be displayed on main page

```
ng g c section1
ng g c section2
```

**section1 .ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'section1',
  templateUrl: './section1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./section1.component.css'],
})
```

**similarly section2 .ts file**

```
@Component({
      selector: 'section2',
      templateUrl: './section2.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./section2.component.css'],
    })
```

***then on the main page you can use multiple sections/components like this***

**page template**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <section1></section1> <!-- component selector -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <section2></section2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea, I am aware that this could work, but the dynamic components need back button functionality and need to change the URL. I could just write my own router, but I'm hoping to use the built-in router functionality.